# Sklearn AdaBoost with Polynomial SVM predicts all 1s

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm, adaboost

I am trying to create a model using AdaBoost with Polynomial SVM as the base classifier.

The code snippet is as follows :

```
base_clf = SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, class_weight='balanced', gamma='scale', probability=True)
model = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=base_clf, n_estimators=10)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_predict = model.predict(X_test)
```

The problem that I am facing is that the model is always predicting only `1`

Is it incorrect to use AdaBoost with SVM as base classifier? Please guide.

Comment: Do you have imbalanced classes ? How did you split train and test

Comment: @Rubens_Zimbres there are 416 of class '1' and 167 of class '0'. I am using the following for splitting data : **train_test_split(features, target, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)**

Answer (score 1):

> Is it incorrect to use AdaBoost with SVM as base classifier? Please guide.

In practice, we **never** use SVMs as base classifiers for Adaboost.

Adaboost (and similar ensemble methods) were conceived ~ 20 years ago using decision trees (DTs) as base classifiers (more specifically, decision *stumps*, i.e. DTs with a depth of only 1); there is good reason why still today, if you don't specify explicitly the `base_classifier` argument, it assumes a value of `DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=1)`, i.e. a decision stump.

DTs are suitable for such ensembling because they are essentially *unstable* classifiers, which is not the case with SVMs, hence the latter are not expected to offer anything when used as base classifiers for boosting algorithms.